# My program keeps changing the color of my entire array to one color instead of different colors for each one

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, colors, console

I am making a little board generator for my class assignment where I take a 2D array and fill it with an object called a "tile" that has its own symbol, background, and foreground color attached to it (i.e. empty = "#", background red, and foreground blue while room = ".", background green, and foreground yellow).

I have gotten the board created and started to draw rooms on it as well as have my tile class. The only problem I have is that whenever I draw my board it only uses the last tile object parameters given so if I drew a room last it has room parameters. I have tried messing around with it by trying change where I created a tile and tried to create a tile to overide it.

Here is the code for my board class code:

```
namespace BrandonPlayerGen
{
public class Board
{
    public static object[,] board;
    public static int height;
    public static int width;
    
    
    
    public static Array MakeBoard(int bwidth, int bheight)
    {
        Tile empty = new Tile("#", ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.Yellow,false);
        board = new object[bheight, bwidth];
        for (int hcheck = 0; hcheck < (bheight-1); hcheck++)
        {
            for(int wcheck = 0; wcheck < (bwidth-1); wcheck++)
            {
                
                
                board[hcheck, wcheck] = empty;
                
            }
        }

        return board;
    }

    
    
    public static void DrawBoard(int dheight, int dwidth)
    {
        dwidth = width;
        dheight = height;
        for (int hcheck = 0; hcheck<dheight; hcheck++)
        {
            for (int wcheck = 0; wcheck < dwidth; wcheck++)
            {
                Tile.DrawTile();
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
    }



    public static Array MakeRoom()
    {
        Tile room = new Tile(".", ConsoleColor.Blue, ConsoleColor.Red,true);

        int bheight = (height-1);
        int bwidth = (width-1);

        int hstart = Random.randInt(1, bheight);
        int wstart = Random.randInt(1, bwidth);
        int rheight = Random.randInt(1, 5);
        int rwidth = Random.randInt(1, 5);

        while (hstart > height || hstart < 1 || wstart < 1 || wstart > width||
            (hstart+rheight)>bheight|| (wstart+rwidth)>bwidth)
        {
            hstart = Random.randInt(1, bheight);
            wstart = Random.randInt(1, bwidth);
            rheight = Random.randInt(1, 5);
            rwidth = Random.randInt(1, 5);
        }

        for (; hstart<rheight; hstart++)
        {
            for (; wstart < rwidth; wstart++)
            {
                board[hstart, wstart] = room;
            }
        }

        return board;

    }
```

Here is the Code for my tile class:

```
namespace BrandonPlayerGen
{
public class Tile
{
    public static string symbol;
    public static ConsoleColor foreColor;
    public static ConsoleColor backColor;
    public static string stairisHere;

    public Tile(string boardSymbol, ConsoleColor 
        back, ConsoleColor fore, bool stairs)
    {
        backColor = back;
        foreColor = fore;
        symbol = boardSymbol;
        if (stairs == true)
        {
            symbol = "<";
            backColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            foreColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }
    }

    public static void DrawTile()
    {
        
        Console.BackgroundColor = backColor;
        Console.ForegroundColor = foreColor;
        Console.Write(symbol);
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

    }

    
}
}
```

Here is where the board is called in main:

```
int height, width;
        Console.Write("Please Enter Board height: ");
        height = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please Enter Board height: ");
        width = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Board.height = height;
        Board.width = width;

        Board.MakeBoard(height, width);
        Board.DrawBoard(Board.height, Board.width);
        Console.ReadKey();
        Board.MakeRoom();
        
        Board.DrawBoard( Board.width, Board.height);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, and sorry if my question is not in the appropriate format this is my first question here.

Edit:
Fixed the way tiles were generated so that a new tile was created each time, but the issue of when I show the board and it is all the same color and symbol across the whole board.

Comment: You are only creating one instance of `Tile`. You need to create a new one (using the `new` keyword) for each cell in your board, i.e. within your inner `for` loop.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make `Tile` a struct so it is passed by value rather than by reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only creating one instance of `Tile`. You need to create a new one for each cell in your board.

Also, unless you plan to contain other things in your board, I suggest its type should be `Tile[,]` and not `object[,]`.

```
board = new Tile[bheight, bwidth];
for (int hcheck = 0; hcheck < (bheight-1); hcheck++)
{
    for(int wcheck = 0; wcheck < (bwidth-1); wcheck++)
    {
        Tile empty = new Tile("#", ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.Yellow,false);            
        board[hcheck, wcheck] = empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @John Wu for your help and I followed what you said and I also changed my room creation by doing the process below. but the color issue still persists.                                                                                                                                     for (; hstart<rheight; hstart++)
            {
                for (; wstart < rwidth; wstart++)
                {
                    Tile room = new Tile(".", ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Blue, false);
                    board[hstart, wstart] = room;
                }
            }

Comment: sorry for bothering you about another comment and thank you for your helo, but after seeing that jumbled mess I decided to spare your eyes the pain of reading that. So I did what you showed and implemented that solution to my MakeRoom function. The problem is the color remains and the symbol remains the same still. Is the problem my DrawTile function or is the problem somewhere else entirely? Any help or at least a lead in the right direction will be gratefully appreciated.